# Does flatmap give better performance than filter+map?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a quite a big dataset (100 million+ records with 100's of columns) that I am processing with spark. I am reading the data into a spark dataset and I want to filter this dataset and map a subset of its fields to a case class.

the code looks somewhat similar,

```
case class Subset(name:String,age:Int)
case class Complete(name:String,field1:String,field2....,age:Int)

val ds = spark.read.format("csv").load("data.csv").as[Complete]

#approach 1
ds.filter(x=>x.age>25).map(x=> Subset(x.name,x.age))

#approach 2
ds.flatMap(x=>if(x.age>25) Seq(Subset(x.name,x.age)) else Seq.empty)
```

Which approach is better? Any additional hints on how I can make this code more performant?

Thanks!

**Edit**

I ran some tests to compare the runtimes and it looks like approach 2 is quite faster, the code i used for getting the runtimes is as follows,

```
val subset = spark.time {
   ds.filter(x=>x.age>25).map(x=> Subset(x.name,x.age))
}

spark.time {
   subset.count()
}

and 

val subset2 = spark.time {
   ds.flatMap(x=>if(x.age>25) Seq(Subset(x.name,x.age)) else Seq.empty)
}

spark.time {
   subset2.count()
}
```

Comment: You can try it out and tell us I suggest.

Comment: I tried with a couple of different datasets, approach #2 is always 2-3 times faster. Why is this the case? I was assuming that both the approaches would be the same, because the DAG optimizer would optimize approach #1.

Comment: Excellent, did you look at explain?

Comment: Your test differs to the assertion in answer below.  I am going to test this myself. +1

Comment: Thanks, i looked at the the explain plan, it seems spark add's a filter step in approach #1 , but not so in approach #2. This would explain the results of my test, but ya not the answer below.

Comment: How did you benchmark the performance of these statements? Did you benchmark the statements using your full dataset? If not, what was the size of the datasets you used for the benchmarking? Did you apply an _action_ to each _transformation_ result (such as `count`)? Without an action, neither transformation will execute.

Comment: Also, what is the type of the data stored in `ds`?

Comment: I am comparing the run times that I get by using  `spark.time`, i ran it on all of my dataset and yes the action was collect. 

the dataset contains custom case class (strings,int's,double's, boolean's) with about around 100 fields.

Comment: Interesting. Can you update your question to post the code you benchmarked, including the commands that you used to run the benchmark? Feel free to simplify the `ds` data type...

Comment: i added the code i used to do the benchmark and also added the ds datatype.

Comment: Just to be clear, did you execute both queries in the same application, with the second dataset evaluated immediately after the first? If so, can you change the order (so that the second query runs first, then the first query) and re-run your benchmark?

Comment: You are right! I was indeed running them one after the other and now when i change the order, the performance is reversed. Let me try this in independent applications and get back to you

Comment: I guessed that might be the case. The _JVM_ is susceptible to all kinds of variances, including _JIT_ compiler performance, garbage collection, other running processses, etc. This makes benchmarking an art form. To get truly accurate results, I'd recommend using a micro-benchmarking tool such as [ScalaMeter](https://scalameter.github.io/). You will need to re-run the same code many times, in forked processes (to ensure that _Spark_ isn't just caching results).

Comment: I would expect your first approach to perform better, as explained in my answer. But it's going to be fairly close. Partitioning is going to be a far bigger factor...

Comment: Yes you are correct, the difference between two of them is negligible. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What I do is use an EMR Cluster from new to test. A little pricey but all things are then equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: My original answer contained an error: *Spark* does support `Seq` as the result of a `flatMap` (and converts the result back into an `Dataset`). Apologies for the confusion. I also added more information on improving the performance of your analysis.

**Update 2**: I missed that you're using a `Dataset` rather than an `RDD` (doh!). This doesn't affect the answer significantly.

*Spark* is a distributed system that partitions data across multiple nodes and processes data in parallel. In terms of efficiency, actions that result in re-partitioning (requiring data to be transferred between nodes) is far more expensive in terms of run-time than in-place modifications. Also, you should note that operations that merely *transform* data, such as `filter`, `map`, `flatMap`, etc. are merely stored and do not execute until an *action* operation is performed (such as `reduce`, `fold`, `aggregate`, etc.). Consequently, neither alternative actually does anything as things stand.

When an action is performed on the result of these transformations, I would expect the `filter` operation to be far more efficient: it only processes data (using the subsequent `map` operation) that passes the predicate `x=>x.age>25` (more typically written as `_.age > 25`). While it may appear that `filter` creates an intermediary collection, it executes lazilly. As a result, *Spark* appears to fuse the `filter` and `map` operations together.

Your `flatMap` operation is, frankly, hideous. It forces processing, sequence creation and subsequent flattening of every data item, which will definitely increase overall processing.

That said, the best way to improve the performance of your analysis is to control the partitioning so that the data is split roughly evenly over as many nodes as possible. Refer to [this guide](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-partitions.html) as a good starting point.

Answer (score -1):

Judging by logic of the syntax the first approach should use less space, since flatMap extends to .map().flatten, both on an argument of equal size. It compiles to the same Java bytecode in the Scala REPL (edit: when using a pet example, which obviously doesn't compensate for actually testing it with comparably large data).

Comment: " It compiles to the same Java bytecode using sbt though." Why do you think so?

Comment: Shouldn't filter use more space? Because it is creating an intermediary collection?